# QRCODE mismatch between Android and IOS Application

Tags: android, ios, qr-code, zxing, android-bitmap

I am developing an Android application which involves generating QRCode.

I have used Zxing library to generate QRCode.

But, It takes white spaces like border around actual qrcode area as below :

[image]

Here in above image white spaces around qrcode is not visible, but I think it is unstandable that what i am saying about.

In IOS, It does not left white spaces as qrcode generated in android application using zxing.

Is there any other library for android that generates **QRCode with no white spaces around it** **or wide white border around it** or tell me for any other solution is possible.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are putting the QR image into an ImageView you could add padding to give a larger border around the QR code.

```
<ImageView
  android:id="@+id/img"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  padding="10dp" />
```

Comment: Did not provided any padding..